# select <select> item by value

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

i have

```
<select id="x">
    <option value="5">hi</option>
    <option value="7">hi 2</option>
</select>
```

I want a javascript function that enables me to select and display the `<option>` as default one by id. In other words, I want to do a `setOption(5)` and the `<option>` with the value "5" to be displayed in the combobox as a default .

Is that possible?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: you shouldn't need even javascript for this. Is there any reason you need to have in done on the client side?

Comment: @fifigyuri - Why not? I can think of several reasons this can be useful. BTW, if jQuery is an option, it's as simple as `$('#x').val('5');`.

Comment: @Kobi clearly there might be reasons for that, but if there aren't then why not drop javascript from the solution? It just wasn't that clear from the question (for me) that javascript is really that important to have.

Comment: Refer this article : http://javascriptstutorial.com/blog/selecting-dropdown-element-using-javascript-or-jquery/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you can, with ES6...

```
function setOption(selectElement, value) {
    return [...selectElement.options].some((option, index) => {
        if (option.value == value) {
            selectElement.selectedIndex = index;
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

...otherwise...

```
function setOption(selectElement, value) {
    var options = selectElement.options;
    for (var i = 0, optionsLength = options.length; i < optionsLength; i++) {
        if (options[i].value == value) {
            selectElement.selectedIndex = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

setOption(document.getElementById('my-select'), 'b');
```

[See it!](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/MvxzK/)

If it returns `false`, then the value could not be found :)

Comment: Thanks , Little fix `for (var i = 0;  i < options.length; i++) `

Comment: @Ronan Dejhero That fix isn't necessary ?

Comment: @Ronan Dejhero It will access the length property for every iteration though :)

Comment: optionsLength = options.length; outside the loop , then use optionsLength inside the loop

Comment: Can it be done without using `i`-like indexes? via `forEach` somehow?

Comment: @Nakilon Yep, but you'd need to use something like `[].forEach.call()` as the options is a `NodeList`, I'd imagine.

Answer (score 6):

If someone looking for jquery solution, use the `val()` function.

```
$("#select").val(valueToBeSelected);
```

In Javascript,

```
document.getElementById("select").value = valueToBeSelected;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery (1.6 or greater)

```
$('#x option[value="5"]').prop('selected', true)
```

Comment: When I try $('#x option[value="5"]') in js-console with my value (visible from inspecting the element), it does not find the option.  If I use $('#x'), it does.  All using my page's element ID, of course.

Comment: I replied to the question, the original question asked "select <select> item by value"

What you are trying to do is something else. and thanks for the down vote for a correct answer :D

Comment: sorry for the misunderstand :) down vote and your comment both come at once, that's why I made a wrong calculation  :)

Answer (score 2):

Using Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('drpSelectSourceLibrary').value = 'Seven';
```

Answer (score 0):

**vanilla JS:**

Get index of search value

```js
var index=[...document.getElementByID('name').options].find(o=>o.value==5).index
```

Set it:

```js
document.getElementByID('name').selectedIndex=index;
```

Answer (score -1):

So I came across this and thought I'd offer a couple of solutions.

The easiest way for a single select, is just to set the value of the select:

```
var mySelect = document.getElementById( 'my-select-id' );
mySelect.value = 7;
```

You can also get the selected option by value just the same way:

```
console.log( mySelect.value );
```

What I was looking for was a better way to set the values of a multiselect (`<select multiple>...</select>`) but as it turns out - it seems you have to loop through the options, and set them in some kind of `for` loop:

```
function setMultiSelectValues( select, values ) {
    for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
        var option = select.options[i];
        if ( values.includes( option.value ) ) {
            option.selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
var mySelect = document.getElementById( 'my-select-id' );
var myValues = [ 'option-1', 'option-5' ];
setMultiSelect( mySelect , values );
```

**Demo:** https://codepen.io/rmorse/pen/QWNymdb

Answer (score -2):

You should not need even javascript to get involved, use simply the `selected` attribute:

```
<select id="x">
  <option value="5" selected>hi</option>
  <option value="7">hi 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Actually i asked for a javascript code to be able to edit the object that has that "selected" attrib

Comment: @Ronan, yeah; but that's the point @fifigyuri was making: **unless** this is being done in **response to user-actions** on the client-side there's **little reason** to use a JavaScript function to achieve this.