# Set selected on options using PHP / JS

Tags: php, javascript, html-select

I have a list of ~80 option values, I *know* there must be an easy way to do this with javascript, would anyone be willing to spare me a moment of their time?

First and foremost, $sid is a get variable pulled from the url (whatever.php?sid=CR01)

Sadly, all option values are hard coded -__- inherited this project

```
<select name="siteid"  size="15">
    <option value="CR01" <?php if ($sid == 'CR01') { echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>
         CR01 (Crooked Run @ Lake Frederick Dam)
    </option>
<option value="'CR02'">CR02 (Nineveh Spring)</option>
<option value="'CR03'">CR03 (Crooked Run @ Rt 639 bridge)</option>
<option value="'CR04'">CR04 (McKay Spring)</option>
<option value="'CR05'">CR05 (Crooked Run @ Cabin Ct)</option>
(etc etc etc)
</select>
```

Comment: What do you want to do with javascript? Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Select Box: set the option on selected with help PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747212/html-select-box-set-the-option-on-selected-with-help-php)

Comment: What you have done is probably the best solution for retaining the selected value since you are getting value $sid. If the list was populated using jquery/javascript then probably jquery would be easy way.

Comment: how do you populate the options in the first place?

Comment: Off topic, but maybe it would be a good idea if you implemented jquery chosen for your multiple select, because is always a better user experience => http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

oh yes ofcourse there is an easy way.

#### IN PHP

```
$opts = array(
    'CR01' => '...',
    'CR02' => '...',
    ....
);

<select name="siteid">
<?php foreach( $opts as $var => $opt ): ?>
  <option 
    value="<?php echo $var ?>"
    <?php if( $var == $sid ): ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?> >
   <?php echo $opt ?>
  </option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

### IN JS

#### VANILLA

```
function setOption(selectElement, value) {
  var options = selectElement.options;
  for (var i = 0, optionsLength = options.length; i < optionsLength; i++) {
    if (options[i].value == value) {
        selectElement.selectedIndex = i;
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
setOption(
  document.querySelector('select[name='siteid']'),
  "<?php echo $sid; ?>"
);
```

[as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324141/select-select-item-by-value)

#### JQUERY

```
$("select[name='siteid'] option[value='<?php echo $sid; ?>']").prop('selected', true)
```

Comment: Sadly all the options are coded out in html and not in an array ><

Comment: It's grabbing the variable, but it isn't doing anything on the front end, did I misplace something? Here's the source: [link]http://pastebin.com/dfdPAqBS

Comment: Your PHP code has an extra pair of quotes surrounding the option value `value="'CR01'"` Remove one pair. or use this: `$("select[name='siteid'] option[value=\"'<?php echo $sid ?>'\"]")`

Comment: also, there was an error in my jquery code, the quotes were mixed up. Now it's ok.

Comment: It **still** doesn't want to run, I'm about to face roll my keyboard and then just write php if/then

Comment: Don't yet do that. Right click on the element and "inspect" the select box option's values. And try playing around in your javascript console with some jquery. It'll strike you.

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript? Why Js? I would use a PHP, to avoid repeating code. Assuming that you have all your options stored in an array, I would do:

```
<select name="siteid"  size="15">
    <?php foreach ( $options as $option ) : ?>
    <option value="'.$option['value'].'"<?php echo ($option['selected'] == 1) ? ' selected="selected"':''?>> <?php echo $option['label'] ?> </option>
    <?php endoreach; ?>
</select>
```

You should get the values from the database, with a sql wich marked a field named selected as 0 if it's not the id, or 1 if it is. This way, you save a crazy amount of coding